# Python multithreading works only a single CPU

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create different threads to work with 8 cores. However I see the code creates 8 threads but only uses around on 100% on my macos.
Why?

```
def runner(i):
    # do random stuff
    for a in range(0,1000000):
        i+=1
        5000 / 34 * i
        i + 400
        i / 20000
        i * 24440
        i+=1
        5000 / 34 * i
        i + 400
        i / 20000

q = queue.Queue()
threads = list()
for x in range(0,80):
    th = threading.Thread(target=runner,args=(x,))
    threads.append(th)

for th in threads:
    th.start()
for th in threads:
    th.join()
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/python-what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). It blocks Python threads to work on a single CPU. 
You can read more about it at https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

> Python GIL is a mutex that protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe.

There are multiple questions on the subject, check out the list here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Python%20GIL)

If you want your code to work on multiple CPUs, check out the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: Or you can disable GIL, but it's not so safety :)

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski in what ways is it safe to disable the GIL?

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski that's really not a good advice

Comment: where did I write that this is safe :)

Comment: @Vinny yeah, I know. that's why I left smile there :)

Comment: So is there a way to use multi-core with threads or I am forced to use multiprocessing?

Comment: You are forced to multiprocessing. There is a way to make threads work on multi cores, but that's just too complicated since multiple modules are not thread safe.