# Python multi thread or multi process parsing text data

Tags: python, parsing, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a huge (>1GB text file) that I want to parse and convert into smaller files.

My text file looks like this:

```
Iteration column1     column2     ....   column 10k
1         data_1_1    data_1_2           data_1_10k
2         data_2_1    data_2_2           data_2_10k
...
10k       data_10k_1    data_10k_2       data_10k_10k
```

I want to parse this text file and convert it into 10k CSV files where each CSV file will contain the following data:

```
Iteration,   column
1,           data_1
2,           data_2
...,
10k,         data_10k
```

I'm looking for the fastest method to do this in python. Would it be possible to parallelize this into 10k chunks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read / process large files in parallel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636059/how-to-read-process-large-files-in-parallel-with-python)

Comment: Please use `GB` for gigabyte.... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you file is "well formatted" you can easily use `numpy` function to load chunks of text files. With `np.loadtxt()` you can set the number of rows to skip and the number of row to read. In this way you can setup a simple for loop, read the file in chunks and write to another file.

If you wish to use `multiprocessing` you have to write a function that reads a chunk of the text file and saves it. Then, using `pool.map()`- or `pool.apply_async()`-methods, you can iterate through the file in a similar way as above but using `multiprocessing`-module.