# How can I run a tkinter GUI application without getting freeze..?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, hashlib

Sorry for my bad English.

I made a file hashing app with tkinter and python3 but as soon it start hashing files User Interface get freeze.

How can I prevent it...?

Comment: Do not run heavy calculations in gui thread.

Comment: As @MichałWalenciak said: Separate your business-logic from your UI-Elements.
If you want more specific help, post your source code.

Comment: Okay I'll upload my project to GitHub and I'll post link of GitHub repo here.

Comment: What should I use threading or multiprocessing..?

Answer (score -1):

Multithreading for I/O operations and Multiprocessing for CPU intensive tasks. Read [What are the differences between the threading and multiprocessing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules)

See also [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)