# How to fix multithreading/multiprocessing with dictionaries?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

I'm making over 100K calls to an api, using 2 functions I reach out to the api with the first function and grab the sysinfo(a dict) for each host, then with the second function I go through sysinfo and grab the IP addresses.  I'm looking for a way to speed this up but never used multiprocessing/threading before(currently takes about 3 hours).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

#pool = ThreadPool(4)
p = Pool(5)

#obviously I removed a lot of the code that generates some of these
#variables, but this is the part that slooooows everything down. 

def get_sys_info(self, host_id, appliance):
    sysinfo = self.hx_request("https://{}:3000//hx/api/v3/hosts/{}/sysinfo"
    return sysinfo

def get_ips_from_sysinfo(self, sysinfo):
    sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
    network_array = sysinfo.get("networkArray", {})
    network_info = network_array.get("networkInfo", [])
    ips = []
    for ni in network_info:
        ip_array = ni.get("ipArray", {})
        ip_info = ip_array.get("ipInfo", [])
        for i in ip_info:
            ips.append(i)
    return ips

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in ids:
        sysinfo = rr.get_sys_info(i, appliance)
        hostname = sysinfo.get("data", {}).get("hostname")
        try:
            ips = p.map(rr.get_ips_from_sysinfo(sysinfo))
        except Exception as e:
            rr.logger.error("Exception on {} -- {}".format(hostname, e))
            continue

#Tried calling it here
ips = p.map(rr.get_ips_from_sysinfo(sysinfo))
```

I have to go through over 100,000 of these api calls, and this is really the part that slows everything down.

I think I've tried everything and gotten every possible iterable, missing argument error.

I'd just really appreciate any type of help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting valid results? You might want to try the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module - it has a nice api.  ... Why do your functions have `self` parameters?

Comment: Those 2 functions are part of  a class, and the whole program does give me accurate results but it just takes waaay too long.  All the simple examples I've seen seem to have lists that they go through...

Comment: Can you get the `sysinfo` from the api AND extract the data you want in a single function? so that you can call/map that single function on each of the hostnames? Or do you know if the bottleneck is the api call only and `sysinfo.get("data", {}).get("hostname")` is a fairly quick process?

Comment: Yeah... we did think about that, there were future projects we were going to grab other information from the sysinfo, BUT I'm going to try that when I get home tonight.

Comment: Your outer loop (over `ids`, whatever those are) is serial, so unless very little time is spent in `get_sys_info` you can’t speed anything up.

Answer (score 2):

you can use threads and queue to communicate, first you will start `get_ips_from_sysinfo` as a single thread to monitor and process any finished `sysinfo` which will store output in `output_list` then fire all `get_sys_info` threads, be careful not to run out of memory with 100k threads

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

jobs = Queue()  # buffer for sysinfo
output_list = []  # store ips

def get_sys_info(self, host_id, appliance):
    sysinfo = self.hx_request("https://{}:3000//hx/api/v3/hosts/{}/sysinfo"
    jobs.put(sysinfo)  # add sysinfo to jobs queue
    return sysinfo  # comment if you don't need it

def get_ips_from_sysinfo(self):
    """it will run contineously untill finish all jobd"""
    while True:
        # get sysinfo from jobs queue
        sysinfo = jobs.get()  # it will wait here for new entry
        if sysinfo == 'exit':
            print('we are done here')
            break

        sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
        network_array = sysinfo.get("networkArray", {})
        network_info = network_array.get("networkInfo", [])
        ips = []
        for ni in network_info:
            ip_array = ni.get("ipArray", {})
            ip_info = ip_array.get("ipInfo", [])
            for i in ip_info:
                ips.append(i)
        output_list.append(ips)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start our listner thread
    Thread(target=rr.get_ips_from_sysinfo)

    threads = []
    for i in ids:
        t = Thread(target=rr.get_sys_info, args=(i, appliance))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    # wait for threads to finish then terminate get_ips_from_sysinfo() by send 'exit' flag
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    jobs.put('exit')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @wwii commented, `concurrent.futures` offer some conveniences that you may help you, particularly since this looks like a batch job.

It appears that your performance hit is most likely to come from the network calls so multithreading is probably more suitable for your use case ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114882/7725670) is a comparison with multiprocessing). If not, you can switch the pool from threads to processes while using the same APIs.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
# You can import ProcessPoolExecutor instead and use the same APIs

def thread_worker(instance, host_id, appliance):
    """Wrapper for your class's `get_sys_info` method"""
    sysinfo = instance.get_sys_info(host_id, appliance)
    return sysinfo, instance

# instantiate the class that contains the methods in your example code
# I will call it `RR`
instances = (RR(*your_args, **your_kwds) for your_args, your_kwds 
    in zip(iterable_of_args, iterable_of_kwds))
all_host_ids = another_iterable
all_appliances = still_another_iterable

if __name__ == "__main__":
   with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:  # assuming 10 threads per core; your example uses 5 processes
        pool = {executor.submit(thread_worker, instance, _id, _app): (_id, _app)
            for _id, _app in zip(instances, all_host_ids, all_appliances)}

        # handle the `sysinfo` dicts as they arrive
        for future in as_completed(pool):
            _result = future.result()
            if isinstance(_sysinfo, Exception):  # just one way of handling exceptions
                # do something
                print(f"{pool[future]} raised {future.result()}")
            else:
                # enqueue results for parallel processing in a separate stage, or
                # process the results serially
                _sysinfo, _instance = _result
                ips = _instance.get_ips_from_sysinfo(_sysinfo)
                # do something with `ips`
```

You can streamline this example by refactoring your methods into functions, if indeed they don't make use of state as seems to be the case in your code.

If extracting the `sysinfo` data is expensive, you can enqueue the results and in turn feed those to a `ProcessPoolExecutor` that calls `get_ips_from_sysinfo` on the queued dicts.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason I was a little leary about calling an instance method in numerous threads - but it seems to work. I made this toy example using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) - hopefully it mimics your actual situation well enough. This submits 4000 instance method calls to a *thread pool* of (at max) 500 workers. Playing around with the `max_workers` value I found that execution time improvements were pretty linear up to about a 1000 workers then the improvement *ratio* started tailing off.

```
import concurrent.futures, time, random

a = [.001*n for n in range(1,4001)]

class F:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = f'{name}:{self.__class__.__name__}'
    def apicall(self,n):
        wait = random.choice(a)
        time.sleep(wait)
        return (n,wait, self.name)

f = F('foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nworkers = 500
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(nworkers) as executor:
#        t = time.time()
        futures = [executor.submit(f.apicall, n) for n in range(4000)]
        results = [future.result() for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
#        t = time.time() - t
#    q = sum(r[1] for r in results)
#    print(f'# workers:{nworkers} - ratio:{q/t}')
```

---

I didn't account for possible Exceptions being thrown during the method call but the example in the docs is pretty clear how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

So... after days of looking at the suggestions on here(thank you so much!!!) And a couple outside reading (Fluent Python Ch 17 and Effective Python 59 Specific Ways..)

```
def get_ips_from_sysinfo(urls):
    sysinfo = lx_request(urls)
    ip_dict =[]
    sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
    hostname = sysinfo.get("hostname")
    network_array = sysinfo.get("networkArray", {})
    network_info = network_array.get("networkInfo", [])
    ips = []
    entry = {}
    entry["hostname"] = hostname
    entry["ip_addrs"] = []
    for ni in network_info:
        ip_array = ni.get("ipArray", {})
        ip_info = ip_array.get("ipInfo", [])
        for ip in ip_info:
            ip_addr = ip.get("ipAddress", None)
            if not ip_addr:
                ip_addr = ip.get("ipv6Address", None)
            if ip is None:
                continue
            if not is_ip_private(ip_addr):
                entry["ip_addrs"].append(ip_addr)
        if len(entry["ip_addrs"]) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            ip_dict.append(entry)
        return ip_dict

urls = get_sys_info(appliance, ids)

def main():
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 15)
    results = list(tqdm(pool.map(get_ips_from_sysinfo, urls), total=len(urls)))
    with open("ip_array.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(results, f,  indent=2, sort_keys=True)

main()
```

*Modified this works now, hope it helps someone else