# Concurrent.futures giving 'NoneType' error but only after around 72,000 iterations

Tags: python

Got great help on concurrency here and actually got it working, or so I thought:
[How to fix multithreading/multiprocessing with dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839622/how-to-fix-multithreading-multiprocessing-with-dictionaries)
...got pulled into some other tasks and just now had a chance to come back to this.  It works great at 50,000, 70,000 and 71,000 iterations but then for some reason it gives a 'NoneType' error, right around 72,000???  Everytime, and the information does seem to be there... it worked without concurrency it just took hours.

```py
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 25)
    results = list(tqdm(pool.map(get_ips_from_sysinfo, urls), total=len(urls)))
```

and then a little of the get_ips_from_sysinfo

```py
def get_ips_from_sysinfo(urls):
    sysinfo = hx_request(urls)
    ip_dict =[]
    sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
    hostname = sysinfo.get("hostname")
    print(hostname)
    network_array = sysinfo.get("networkArray", {})
    network_info = network_array.get("networkInfo", [])
```

Works at 69,000 70,000 71,000 
I don't understand why it works up until around 72,000???

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RiskReportV2_concurrent.py", line 282, in <module>
    concurrency(appliance)
  File "RiskReportV2_concurrent.py", line 267, in concurrency
    results = list(tqdm(pool.map(get_ips_from_sysinfo, urls), total=len(urls)))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/money/Documents/riskreport/src/tqdm/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1022, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 556, in result_iterator
    yield future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "RiskReportV2_concurrent.py", line 135, in get_ips_from_sysinfo
    sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Finally had a chance to look at this again and I have no idea if I did this right or not but switching the function around to this, works

```py
def get_ips_from_sysinfo(urls):
    sysinfo = hx_request(urls)
    ip_dict =[]
    if not sysinfo:
        print("None")
    else:
        sysinfo = sysinfo["data"]
```

...hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

See answer up there below

Finally had a chance to look at this again and I have no idea if I did this right or not but switching the function around to this, works