# Multithreading for double list

Tags: python, multithreading

I m new to programming, I have searched and looked at other SO posts regarding multithread, my title may be misleading but I'll try to explain in brief!

I want to understand how I keep passing 2 args from 2 different lists.

so for example.

If I have 2 lists.

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['d','e','f']
```

And I want to loop through this list and pass those in a function but using multithreading.

normal for loop would be something like this..

```
def do_something(l1, l2):
    print(l1)
    print(l2)

for l1, l2 in zip(l11, l22):
  do_something(l11, l22)
```

But I want to use multithreading for this process, so it would print all both list value together...

so far I've tried this but its not working.

```
threads = [] 
for l1, l2 in zip(l11, l22):    
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=do_something, args=(l11, l22)))  
    threads[-1].start()
    
for t in threads:                                                           
    t.join()
```

Can someone please explain to me how multi-threading works in a simple way?
And How do I achieve the above results?

**Thinking from a larger point of view if I m comparing multiple 2 huge excel files where I have to give column names for both excel in a function. How can I run the function parallelly so it wont wait for the first iteration to finish?**

Comment: You are resetting `threads` to an empty list each time the loop iterates. Put `threads = []` *before* the loop, not in it.

Comment: @chepner Aah, Rookie mistake. I fixed it and tried it's still doing one iteration per time. and it didn't even go for the other after completing first.

Comment: In Python, multithreading only helps with I/O-bound workloads.  Unless you are waiting for I/O, the "global interpreter lock" means only one Python thread can execute at a time.  The others will wait.

Comment: Generally, use threading for i/o bound tasks and multiprocessing for cpu bound tasks. [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python), [What are the differences between the threading and multiprocessing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules)

Comment: @TimRoberts Maybe I didn't understand what you said but I m not waiting for any I/O, I have the list ready from which I have to pass each value to a function.

Comment: Right.  You don't have any I/O, so multithreading will not help you one bit.  It will still take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thinking from a larger point of view if I m comparing multiple 2 huge excel files where I have to give column names for both excel in a function. How can I run the function parallelly so it wont wait for the first iteration to finish?

Python does not benefit of threading in CPU-Bound operations. For that you would need Multiprocessing.

Beware that in windows it gets very complex very fast, and it is *very* slow to launch processes. To the point that unless it is taking multiple seconds to process it does not help.
Besides [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) you also have [Starmap from multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap).

Comment: What If I m comparing multiple tables from 2 databases?

Comment: If you include the querying in the task, then it would definitely help. But _not_ if you split only the post-processing.
If you are planning to launch multiple items, check [threadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) as it recycles the threads, as workers.