# Multi thread and join results as opposed to loops - scraping Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

I am scraping 5 links and sorting like so:

```
def getTable():

    p = getLinksToScrape()#returns 5 urls    
    all = getLinksData(p[0])
    starting = 1
    l = 5
    while starting < l:
        allStart = getLinksData(p[starting])
        if allStart:           
            all = all + allStart   
            all = sorted(all, key=lambda x: float(x[6])) 
        starting = starting + 1
    return all
```

This works but is very slow, so I would like to scrape all 5 urls at the same time (and to combine/join and sort the results) and am wondering what the best way to do this would be?
I tried the following:

```
all = ""

def getTable(url):

    global all
    all.append(getLinksData(url))
    
def main():

 global all
 p = getLinksToScrape()#returns 5 urls
 p1 = Process(target=getTable, args=(p[0],))
 p2 = Process(target=getTable, args=(p[1],))
 p3 = Process(target=getTable, args=(p[2],))
 p4 = Process(target=getTable, args=(p[3],))
 p5 = Process(target=getTable, args=(p[4],))
 p1.start()
 p2.start()
 p3.start() 
 p4.start()
 p5.start()
 p1.join()
 p2.join()
 p3.join()
 p4.join()
 p5.join()
 all = sorted(all, key=lambda x: float(x[6])) 

main()
```

But this is not working.  What would be the best way to multi thread this loop? Cheers.

Comment: When you say that it’s not working, can you be more specific?  Is it crashing?

Comment: Unlike threads, multiprocessing processes do not share memory by default.  Each process gets its own "global" `all` variable.  Look at the documentation for multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=list#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list)

Comment: You might also want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules to see whether you need multiprocessing or threads.  In short if each "process" is slow because you are doing a lot of CPU processing, then you need multiprocessing and the slightly more complicated memory handling.  If each "process" is slow because you are waiting for IO, then use threads and your simple `global all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple processes don't share the same global variables, it's better to get the results from the execution

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor


def get_links_data(url):
    return ...


urls = [...]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_links_data, urls)

sorted(results, key=lambda x: float(x[6]))
```

P.S. don't use `all` as a variable it's a built-in function.