# Running a long, blocking, python script on_message with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm creating my first Discord bot in Python (hosted locally, for security), and the main function is meant to be running a cheat-detection script when asked. The issue is that cheat-detection script is long, and blocking, and after it starts, relatively quickly, the heartbeat is interrupted and errors are thrown. At that point, the underlying cheater script seems to stop. I need to somehow get the fetch script to run "outside" the on_message event so that it can complete while the bot keeps listening and sending the pings. The relevant bot code is:

```
...
# EVENT LISTENER FOR WHEN A NEW MESSAGE IS SENT TO A CHANNEL.
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global wallet
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    msg = message.content
    channel = message.channel
    # CHECKS IF THE MESSAGE THAT WAS SENT CONTAINS "HELLO".
    if "check wallet" in str(msg).lower() and str(channel) == "gus":
        # SENDS BACK A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL.
        wallet = msg[13:]
        fetch(wallet)
        await message.channel.send(f'Some day this will run a cheater check on {wallet}. But not today ;P')
    if "hello" in str(msg).lower():
        # SENDS BACK A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL.
        await message.channel.send("Hi, where's Shawn?")
    if report != "":
        await message.channel.send(report)
# EXECUTES THE BOT WITH THE SPECIFIED TOKEN.
bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

"fetch(wallet)" is the massive cheater detection script. I had tried when I first wrote it to use async, but I don't think it's possible given how it works. It makes hundreds of thousands of API calls, and parses millions of items in lists, deques, dicts, etc. In some cases, it can take 1-2 minutes. In others, up to 30 minutes.

What I need to do is have fetch run in a new thread, or externally somehow so that the bot is not blocked, and to make sure it completes itself. It can just send a simple printout to Discord, or else return the printout to the main bot on_message for printing on command (as seen here with my attempt to wait for a report and then send it).

I've read through docs on subprocesses, and re-read async info, but neither seem to solve the problems.
Is there a way to allow for a long set of functions to run without disrupting the bot and thus the external functions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be a perfect place to use `multiprocessing` or `threading`, you can read up on the differences in the docs.

But ill go with `multiprocessing` for the answer.

Instead of calling your fetch method directly you can call it as follows.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=fetch, args=(wallet,))
p.start()
```

This creates a subprocess that runs your function (which i feel like you were trying to accomplish with the `subprocess` module, the names are similar)
and depending on how often this `on_message` event runs you can either just ignore the process and leave it to die or end on its own, or you can append them to a list and check them every time `on_message` runs.

Note: please make sure the fetch method has no "side effects."
Meaning the function shouldn't change any variables or state outside of itself, if it does you can try `threading`, but it's unrecomended to design it like that.

The Docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

A good write up on the differences between multiprocessing and threading.
[What are the differences between the threading and multiprocessing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules)

Comment: Thanks! I tried simply adding this in, and I'm getting a duplicate handle error. I will read through the docs and see if I can figure out how to implement this with my code. Unless there's an issue already with that error?

Comment: @briangilbert can you paste the actual exception? Ive never heard of that before haha. Its possible it comes from inside your `fetch` function, which if thats the case, just find where it is. It doesnt sound like something the multiprocessing module itself would throw. you can even try `threading` to see if its something to do with the file system and locks between processes.

Comment: This is the end of the exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 111, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: @briangilbert how are you running the script? is it running as a user or a service? The error is a windows error, you may can google around and see if thats an issue. or try the `threading` module, very similar

Comment: I tried a number of different things from all the help, but nothing really solved this. In the end, it turned out that by careful coding, the bot continues to work even while busy with the blocking code. I just try to have it come out of the blocking code periodically before running another piece. So, solved, but not really ;)